# : java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "hosturl": No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android

I have android application which connect to `"hosturl"` over the web. This application can connect to `hosturl` in the initial steps, but after i try to test it for some time(say 20 or more requests), I get above exception and I can not no longer connect to above url.

If i restart my android handset, then application can again connect to the `"hosturl"` but again I get the exception after I have tried to connect to `hosturl` few number of times

Could anybody help me here If you have encounter such a behavior with an android application before.

Comment: I've seen this exception when the device loses Internet connectivity, when you get that exception can you visit the url in the browser?

Comment: yep, i can connect to the internet with other applications when I get this exception with my android application

Comment: I will repeat his question: can you visit *that URL* in the browser? Not just keeping the connection, because if the site is not under your control, it may be throttling access (especially if it's a lot of requests in a very short time --- like automated requests by code in a loop, for example). No network expert here, but if it's dropping your connections, I guess this should be the expected behavior.

Comment: yep, I can connect to "hosturl" in the browser when i get this exception

Comment: I had the same issue and come to know **"There was some issue with DNS for that particular domain."**

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have the INTERNET permission. Try adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml file, right before `</manifest>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: If you have read his question carefully, I am sure that you would have spotted `This application can connect to hosturl in the initial steps, but after i try to test it for some time(say 20 or more requests)`, which means that the application `can connect to Internet`.

Answer (score 2):

I met this and I just closed my AVD and start it again and it worked...

Comment: What a huge time sink this was. Seems like it happened when I moved from my home network to my work network. Restarting AVD did indeed fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Internet connection.
Check Wifi.
Check Server.